Is there a way to force enable Reader View in Firefox Android on pages where the icon doesn't appear?
From this question about Firefox in general I have tried everything except the custom css answer. How can I force enable Reader Mode in the Android app? Even the about:config page won't open. Maybe it's at a different location or something.
